# How to assign a specific [x] value to port pin?

Tags: c, avr

How can I assign dynamic value to a pin a specific pin on my AVR chip. 
For instance I have:

```
void life_reset(void){
    PORTC |= (1<<PC0);
    PORTC |= (1<<PC1);
    PORTC |= (1<<PC2);
    life_number = 2;
}
void lost_life(void){
            life_number--;
            PORTC &= ~(1<<PC2);
}
```

Which decrements my `life_number` variable and bitwise AND's the left shift of PC2.

In this case, each `PC[x]` value is connected to an LED.
How can I write my `PORTC &=` statement to be the `PC[x]` value of `life_number`.

**Pseudocode -what I want to do**

```
void lost_life(void){
            life_number--;
            PORTC &= ~(1<<PC[*life_number*]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the life number, because the PCn macros are in fact just the same numbers that show in their name.

```
PORTC &= ~(1<<life_number);
```

Comment: Just as a side note for Dan: This would only work properly for `life_number` values ranging from 0 to 7 and only one respective LED (PC0-PC7) would light up at a time. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Rev1.0 Yes, it is what I wanted, sorry if my terminology was a bit off! Just theoretically enhancing the question.. If for instance I had `life_numbers` that were not in this range, I would be able to direct which LED (PC0-PC7) to light up through a series of `if statements` wouldn't I?<br>
eg.<br>
`If (life_number == 102){ <br>
     PORTC &= ~(1<<PCn)<br>
}`<br>

Comment: @Dan: Sure. I would probably use it as a health bar where 8 LEDs are lit on full health, 4 on half and 0 when "dead".